# Go game set with balls or spheres

Tags: go, components

Once in a documentary I saw an exquisite Go Set.
The stones were not double or single convex, they were actually balls (round spherical stones).
The board had carved channels or grooves, so as you put a ball to an intersection it stayed there.

I tried to find such a board on the internet and could not even find a picture.
Does anybody know of such boards?
(I am not interested kurokigoishi boards, they might be exquisite, but they are not balls).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GO ARK](http://goark.jp) , a 9x9 Go set designed by Japanese designer Junji Masamitsu, fits your description.  The set is also sold on amazon.jp, shown as "out of stock" at the moment.

Comment: Good for a start. However what I the board was from wood and the marbles where not translucent.